# How to use Serverspec to test the utility installed in other user?

Tags: chef-infra, serverspec

My requirement is that I need to run a utility that is installed in other user and I have to check the output returned from that session and verify it.
**Example :**

- I installed java as *srijava* user
- Now in Serverspec I wrote the command to test the Java version (Assume that the `java -version` runs  only in that user and not as *root*).
- if I use `su srijava`, then I do not get the output returned back to the root session and the test fails.
- If I run without `su srijava` then my utility will throw an  error
  that the user is not *SriJava*

Code with `su` :

```ruby
describe command('su srijava ; cd /app/java; ./java --version') do
  its(:stdout) { should contain('1.7') }
end
```

Code without `su`:

```ruby
describe command('cd /app/java; ./java --version') do
  its(:stdout) { should contain('1.7') }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```ruby
describe command("su -c '/app/java/java --version' srijava") do
  its(:stdout) { should contain('1.7') }
end
```

FYI you are using RSpec 2 and soon to be obsolete Serverspec syntax for your matcher. Consider futureproofing it with:

```ruby
describe command("su -c '/app/java/java --version' srijava") do
  its(:stdout) { is_expected.to match(/1\.7/) }
end
```

Comment: Should with no receiver isn't deprecated AFAIK, it's the `object.should` that got whacked.

Comment: @coderanger I didn't say anything about deprecated anything. What are you referring to?

Comment: You said "Rspec 2" and "obsolete", I think because you confused the two forms of using `should`. The receiverless is still present in Rspec 3 and is not obsolete (and is used in all Serverspec examples). As such, you should remove that part of the answer as it is incorrect :)

Comment: @coderanger I still have no idea what you are talking about. I said it was using RSpec 2 (`should`) and soon to be obsolete Serverspec (`contain`) matcher syntax. This is absolutely and unequivocally correct. I recommend reading RSpec and Serverspec documentation if this is still unclear because I don't want to have a big side instruction in the comments here. Thanks.